# Firestore onSnapshot in react

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I have a page that redirects to a stripe checkout in my react app.

The way this works is it creates a a firestore document which generates a URL for the checkout.

The setDoc method in the code below works great. A new document is created that contains the URL needed.

The issue is with the onSnapshot section in the code. I expected this to redirect to the URL from the newly created document, however it returns an error instead: TypeError: docRef.onSnapshot is not a function

```
  const docRef = collection(Firestoredb, 'customers', '8UAC7GBYSHW1jTToBgGTLyYxtXJ2', 'checkout_sessions');
  setDoc(doc(docRef), {
    price: 'price_1LaJC1CKMdmWgnyspBbFet9v',
    success_url: window.location.origin,
    cancel_url: window.location.origin,
  });


// Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
docRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
  const { error, url } = snap.data();
  if (error) {
    // Show an error to your customer and
    // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console.
    alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
  }
  if (url) {
    // We have a Stripe Checkout URL, let's redirect.
    window.location.assign(url);
    setPayURL(url);
  }
})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax of [onSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) quite resembles the one for setDoc
`onSnapshot(doc(docRef), (snap)=> {})`.

Another way of handling this is to await for the setDoc and then use [getDoc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document). Your code will look something like this:

```
async function(){
  const docRef = collection(Firestoredb, 'customers', '8UAC7GBYSHW1jTToBgGTLyYxtXJ2', 'checkout_sessions');
  await setDoc(doc(docRef), {
    price: 'price_1LaJC1CKMdmWgnyspBbFet9v',
    success_url: window.location.origin,
    cancel_url: window.location.origin,
  });
  
  const snap = await getDoc(doc(docRef));  
  const { error, url } = snap.data();
  if (error) {
    // Show an error to your customer and
    // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console.
    alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
  }
  if (url) {
    // We have a Stripe Checkout URL, let's redirect.
    window.location.assign(url);
    setPayURL(url);
  }
}
```